# <br> Tag under buttons

Tags: button, border

I'm just starting to learn HTML, and I'm stuck with this problem. I'm trying to create buttons with a border underneath but with my code, the border only partially shows up. Any suggestions? Thanks!

What I have:

```
<div>
<h1>
<a href="index.htm" target="_self"><button class="btn-group">Home</button></a>
<a href="newpage.htm" target="_self"><button class="btn-group">Test</button></a>
</h1?
</div>

<br>
```

Here is a fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/koalamonkeys/17rhwcvt/

Comment: The tag for a horizontal line is `<hr>` (**h**orizontal **r**ule), `<br>` is a **br**eakline.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few issues with your HTML:

- The buttons are in a `<h1>` tag, which also isn't closed properly (`</h1?`). Remove these `h1` completely.
- One of the `div`s isn't closed. Add another `</div>` after the existing one.

The horizontal line should then be full width.

Although it has no effect on the line, there is also a superfluous `</style>` towards the end.

JSFiddle highlights tag issues with a red background. You should strive to resolve any such issues to avoid unpredictable rendering of the page.

Comment: Thanks so much! I removed the h1 tags and the extra </style>, but I can't find the open div.

Comment: Both div are closed is the JSFiddle. You'll want to move the `<hr>` outside both divs for the line to go the full width.

Comment: Great. Please consider [accepting the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) (tick next to the answer) to mark it as solved.